# Equal height to width, single images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I add class "equal" if an image that is  equal in width and height.

Here is my code:

```
var img = $('img', this);
var width = img.width();
var height = img.height();

if(width == height){
$(this).img.addClass('equal');
}
```

Comment: now sure you can do `$(this).img.addClass('equal');` If you want to se a class on an image use `img.addClass('equal');` . Also what should $(this) refer to in your code

Comment: Try doing this: `img.addClass('equal');`

Comment: `$(this)` does not make sense in your code, unless you are iterating through a collection of images. Also, you might want to wait for the image to finish loading first: the width and height of images are unavailable if they have not been loaded.

Comment: It is a collection of images! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get all images
2. Iterate and add the class.

   ```
   //get all images
   let $images = $('img');

   // add classes
   $.each($images, function(key, img) { 

       if ( img.height === img.width )  {
          $(img).addClass('equal'); 
       }

   });
   ```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/6ot4ks87/

Comment: But wouldn't that add class to all images?

Comment: forgot to tag you! @stavm

Comment: @Angelica added an example.

Answer (score 1):

This bit:

```
if(width == height){
    $(this).img.addClass('equal');
}
```

should be:

```
if(width == height){
    img.addClass('equal');
}
```

as you already have your `img` as a jQuery object (by doing `var img = $('img', this);`)